# Why does django-dynamic-formset 'add another' button duplicate foreign key field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I went through the [instructions](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst) to set up django-dynamic-formset to my project and my specific inline formsets.

{{ Edit }}

The goal is to provide an easy way to add and remove individual forms within an formset.

{{ End edit }}

All of the formsets seem to work except one that includes a foreign key. When I 'add another' it duplicates that field right under it.

Before pressing 'add another':
[image]

After pressing 'add another':
[image]

The formset:

```
<h3>Services</h3>
<div class="row">  
    {{ services_formset.management_form }}
    {% for formserve in services_formset %}
    {{ formserve.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="container" id="services_formset">
        <div class="row" name="service_form">    
            {% for hidden in formserve.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}                                         
            {% for field in formserve %}
                {% if field.name != 'index' and field.name != 'invoice'%}
                    <div class="col-sm">                     
                        {{ field.errors }}
                        {{ field|as_crispy_field }}
                        {% if field.help_text %}
                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}                
        </div>
     </div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#services_formset').formset({
            prefix: '{{ formserve.prefix }}'
        });
    })

</script>
```

EDIT:
I use `inlineformset_factory` to create it:

```
ServicesFormset = inlineformset_factory(TransactionsTable, TransSpTable, fields=('service','fee','qty','taxrate','tax','sub'), extra=1, widgets=services_widgets, can_delete=True)
```

I then instantiate it using a function that checks if it's a create or detail view and a POST or not:

```
context['services_formset'] = get_dynamic_formset(self, ServicesFormset)

def get_dynamic_formset(view, FormSetClass):
    if view.object:
        if view.request.POST:
            dynamic_formset = FormSetClass(view.request.POST, instance=view.object)
        else:
            dynamic_formset = FormSetClass(instance=view.object)
    else:
        if view.request.POST:
            dynamic_formset = FormSetClass(view.request.POST)
        else:
            dynamic_formset = FormSetClass()   
    return dynamic_formset
```

Comment: Can you show your Views as well as Forms?

Comment: can you explain in a little detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: @YantraLogistics thanks. My view is pretty lengthy. It's a CBV. I write custom get_context_data and get_template_names functions otherwise it's all pretty vanilla. I updated the original question with the form information.

Comment: @FaisalManzer thanks. I added a very brief explanation in the first part of the question look for: {{ Edit }}. I know it's short but let me know if you'd like more clarification.

Comment: Was the answer to this problem ever determined?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I determined that if you make sure that you have extra set to 1, this issue goes away.  If extra is set to 0, it duplicates foreign keys for whatever reason.  The short term fix for me was to set extra to 1, although it's not an optimal solution for me but a short term fix.